# ¿Como cambiar símbolo de un DecimalFormat?

Tags: java, android, edittext

Ayer buscando mascaras para un `EditText` , encontré aquí en el sitio el siguiente fragmento de código :

```
public static TextWatcher amount(final EditText editText) {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }
        private String current = "";
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().equals(current)){
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "");

                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));

                current = formatted;
                editText.setText(formatted);
                editText.setSelection(formatted.length());

                editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

en cual utilizo asi

```
 final EditText txtMountCashOut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMountCashOut);
    txtMountCashOut.addTextChangedListener(CashOut.amount(txtMountCashOut));
```

ahora lo que no entiendo es porque cuando voy a escribir me aparece un signo de pesos adelante del 0.00 , como en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A mi me gustaria poder ponerle otra cosa , como por ejemplo USD

> la fuente del codigo esta en esta pregunta
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107901/better-way-to-format-currency-input-edittext

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info): Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Comment: tenes razon , mala mia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando la instancia de `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`, puedes cambiar el simbolo utilizando el metodo `setDecimalFormatSymbols(simbolFormat)`:

```
//..
if(!s.toString().equals(current)){
    editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "");

    double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
    // Obtienes la instancia del formateador
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    // obtener la instancia del formatiador de simbolos
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = decimalFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

    // cambias el simbolo por US
    symbols.setCurrencySymbol("US");

    // le asignamos el nuevo formateador de simbolo
    formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);

    // formateamos
    String formatted = decimalFormat.format((parsed/100))

     current = formatted;
    editText.setText(formatted);
    editText.setSelection(formatted.length());

    editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
//...
```

Esto lo que hace es cambiar el formateador de simbolos del decimalFormatter a US

Comment: Muchas gracias Einer!